# How would I say in between () and () year in Russian?

Tags: словоупотребление

What if it's , "**Между** 1905 и 1914 годами"? How would you say the ending of the two years?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Между ...пят**ым** и ...четырнадцат**ым** годами.

Comment: Also, how would I say, "In 1941"?

Thanks so much for the information

Comment: @NP, "in 1941" - "в тысяча девятьсот сорок первом (году)"

Comment: Разговорно, можно сказать просто "в сорок первом году." Все поймут что речь идет о 1941-м году.

Answer (score 2):

I would say `С 1905-го по 2014-й`.

We don't usually say "between years" in Russian, as an idiom.

Comment: Valuable answer! Actually, we can say "между" in contexts like "Это событие имело место между 1905 и 2014 годами, но более точно мы не знаем." or "Разница между 1905 и 2014 годами огромна!", or "Промежуток между 1905 и 2014 годами наполнен важнейшими историческими событиями". But in context "Такие-то события происходили с 1905 по 2014 (т.е. начались в 1905 и закончились в 2014)" we really have to use "с 1905 по 2014", not "между 1905 и 2014".

Comment: @Lara I believe in English this different is conferred as `between` vs `in between`, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Maybe! But I'm not sure. Does anyone know?

Comment: @alamar "In between" would never be used with years, except adverbially ("in 2005, or 2008, or sometime in between").

Comment: @Lara, in English you could say "The old man lived from 1905 to 2014". On the other hand, you could say "All of the houses on this street were built between 1900 and 1950". So I think the English usage would be similar to the Russian usage: one expression for a continuous process with a starting year and an ending year, and the other expression for a range of years, a minimum and a maximum, within which some events occurred.